# Making a group with spaces between words and decimals

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I'm not new to the concept of regex but the syntax and semantics of everything get confusing for me at times. I have been trying to create a pattern to recognize

```
Ambient Relative Humidity: 31.59
```

With the grouping

```
Ambient Relative Humidity (Group 1)

31.59 (Group 2)
```

But I also need to be able to match things such as

```
Operator: Bob
```

With the grouping

```
Operator (Group 1)

Bob (Group 2)
```

Or

```
Sensor Number: 0001
```

With the grouping

```
Sensor Number (Group 1)

0001 (Group 2)
```

Here is the current pattern I created which works for the examples involving operator and sensor number but does not match with the first example (ambient humidity)

```
\s*([A-Za-z0-9]*\s*?[A-Za-z0-9]*)\s*:\s*([A-Za-z0-9]*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add more space separated key parts to the regex.
Also, you have to add an option for decimal numbers in the value.

Something like this  `([A-Za-z0-9]*(?:\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+)*)\s*:\s*((?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)|[A-Za-z0-9]+)?`

https://regex101.com/r/fl0wtb/1

Explained

```
 (                             # (1 start), Key
      [A-Za-z0-9]* 
      (?: \s* [A-Za-z0-9]+ )*
 )                             # (1 end)
 \s* : \s* 
 (                             # (2 start), Value
      (?:                           # Decimal number
           \d+ 
           (?: \. \d* )?
        |  \. \d+ 
      )
   |                              # or,
      [A-Za-z0-9]+                  # Alpha num's
 )?                            # (2 end)
```

Answer (score 1):

I may have posted too soon without thinking, I now have the following expression

```
\s*([A-Za-z0-9]*\s*[A-Za-z0-9]*\s*[A-Za-z0-9]*)\s*:\s*([A-Za-z0-9.]*)
```

The only thing is that it includes spaces sometimes that I was trying to avoid but I can just trim those later. Sorry for posting so soon!

Answer (score 0):

```
var st = "Ambient Relative Humidity: 31.59 Operator: Bob Sensor Number: 0001";
var li = Regex.Matches(st, @"([\w]+?:)\s+(\d+\.?\d+|\w+)").Cast<Match>().ToList();

    foreach (var t in li)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Group 1 {t.Groups[1]}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Group 2 {t.Groups[2]}");
    }

    //Group 1 Humidity:
    //Group 2 31.59
    //Group 1 Operator:
    //Group 2 Bob
    //Group 1 Number:
    //Group 2 0001
```